# Does Git support local names for submodule URLs?

Tags: git

Git has a nice mechanism to give local names to remote repositories. This mechanism simplifies a lot. Also Git supports submodules and keeps the submodule repository URLs right in the .gitmodules file by their absolute addresses. But does Git support adding names rather than absolute URLs to the submodules registry?

For example, let's say I have a multi-module repository and one day I decide to migrate from one Git hosting service to another, or my local network addresses change or we migrate to another system with different paths. After such a migration I need to fix the URLs by a new commit, but when I'd like to checkout a specific tag from the past, this would attempt to fetch repositories from the old service that would result in a non-existing repository error. In this case absolute URLs are not easy to use.

Is it possible to give names to  submodule addresses, so that I could change the addresses similarly to the remotes and not run into the issue? Or if I choose a certain URL, then I'm stuck to it forever (I'm not taking history-rewriting into account)?

Comment: When you migrated you changed the URL of the superproject using `git remote set-url`, right? You need to do that for all migrated submodules. Submodules are just separate repositories with separate configs. `cd` into every submodule directory and run `git remote set-url`. Return to the superproject and fix URLs in `.gitmodules`. Run `git submodule sync`. Add, commit, push.

Comment: @phd How would this affect the history? As far as I understand, the old URLs would remain in  .gitmodules, correct?

Comment: @phd I mean, they would remain in the `.gitmodules` history. What I'm thinking of is giving some names to the URLs (like `git remote`) so that `.gitmodules` would become URLs-independent. Or am I still wrong about that?

Comment: There is no such aliases. Why do you care about `gitmodules` history? Just fix URLs there and go on.

Comment: @phd Not at a git repo now, but what I'm trying to understand is: if I should not care the `.gitmodules` history, what would git do when I checkout a tag prior to the URLs change? Doesn't it checkout `.gitmodules` that refer URLs that do not exist anymore?

Comment: Of course it does but it doesn't matter. `git` doesn't use URLs from `.gitmodules` — it uses URLs from `.git/config`; it's `git submodule sync` that put them there. So if you checkout an old tag but do not run `git submodule sync` git will use your new migrated URLs.

Comment: @phd Ah, this is how it's supposed to work? I didn't know that git does not use URLs from `.gitmodules` -- I just thought I elaborated my concern poorly. It still sounds tricky, and I have to play with it more to get better understanding but it looks really cool. It's really interesting and probably the idea of URL names might be bad (have to get into submodules sync deeper). If you put your comments as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Submodules are indeed tricky. Giving these things names wouldn't directly help though: you need an indirection that happens at `git clone` or `git submodule init` time and the only real way to get that for all cases is to use the `insteadOf` trick. On the other hand, names *relative to a superproject* would be useful in Git, but they don't exist.

Comment: @phd I'm very sorry to disturb you, could you please post your answer so that I could close my question since your answer really clarifies what I was concerned about? I really appreciate your comments and believe it would cover anyone else's concerns about how Git submodules work too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submodules are separate repositories with separate configs. `cd` into every submodule directory and run `git remote set-url`. This allows to update the submodule separately using `git pull`.

Return to the superproject and fix URLs in `.gitmodules`; edit the file or run `git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<local-path>.url <URL>` (`<local-path>` and `<URL>` are just placeholders).

Run `git submodule sync`; this transfers the updated URLs from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config` of the superproject. Git really doesn't use URLs from `.gitmodules`, only from `.git/config`. `.gitmodules` is the way to preserve the list of submodules and their URLs in the repository. To make `git` know about the URLs `git sync` is required. `git clone --recursive` calls `git sync` automatically.

`git add`, `git commit`, `git push` to save and publish your changes in `gitmodules` and submodules.